# SQL syntax error in MySQL server version when getting data from SAP

Tags: java, mysql

I am getting data from SAP an update a flag in MYSQL DB table according to that response. But my query gave me an SQL syntax error every time (see log below). Connection between JAVA and SAP is ok. I can send data to SAP. It is working.

- **tbl_po_data** is my MYSQL table.
- **table.getName()** is to get my SAP table name.
- **FLAG** is SAP table flag field.

This is my method.

```
private void tableOparator(Table table) throws Exception {

        pooler = DBPool_POSMS.getInstance();
        dataSource = pooler.getDataSource();
        Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();
        con.setAutoCommit(false);

        qex = new DBTableQueryExcecutre(con);

        for (int i = 0; i < table.getNumRows(); i++) {
            table.setRow(i);

            String sbQuery2 = "update tbl_po_data set status = 'X' where reference_no " + " in (SELECT REFNO from '"
                    + table.getName() + "' where FLAG = 'X')";

            int rcount = qex.runQuery(sbQuery2);
                System.out.println("tbl_po_data Rows -->" + rcount + "Status Updated");
                con.commit();

        }

        qex.closeConnections();

    }
```

My LOGCAT

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''ZSLPOSMSTBL' where FLAG = 'X')' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor1.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2809)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1811)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1725)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingStatement.java:228)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingStatement.java:228)
    at DBTableQueryExcecutre.runQuery(DBTableQueryExcecutre.java:52)
    at CreatePO.tableOparator(CreatePO.java:203)
    at CreatePO.sendDataToSap(CreatePO.java:170)
    at CreatePO.run(CreatePO.java:53)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: And do you expect us to use our mind reading skills to find out what error message you received or are you going to share it with us?

Comment: Your table name is being put in single quotes. Remove the quotes.

Comment: Use this: `(SELECT REFNO from " + table.getName() + " where FLAG = 'X')";`

Comment: now i am getting a error called **"com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'po_sms.ZSLPOSMSTBL' doesn't exist"**

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to select from a String value
`'ZSLPOSMSTBL'` instead of your table name `ZSLPOSMSTBL`

Remove the quotes in your SQL statement and it should work.

```
"update tbl_po_data set status = 'X' where reference_no " + " in (SELECT REFNO from "
                + table.getName() + " where FLAG = 'X');"
```

Comment: now i am getting a error called **"com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'po_sms.ZSLPOSMSTBL' doesn't exist"**

Comment: So, your `table.getName()` returns a table name that doesn't exist